# Access one object attribute in another attribute

Tags: php, attributes

When I try to do the following I get a `syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE`. What am I doing wrong?

```
class myObj {
  public $birth_month;
  public $birthday = array('input_val' => $this->birth_month);
}
```

I also tried

```
class myObj {
  public $birth_month;
  public $birthday = array('input_val' => $birth_month);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use an expression to initialize a class property. It must be a constant value, or you must initialize it in the constructor.  That's the source of your syntax error.

```
class myObj {
  public $birth_month;
  public $birthday;

  // Initialize it in the constructor
  public function __construct($birth_month) {
    $this->birth_month = $birth_month;
    $this->birthday = array('input_val' => $this->birth_month);
  }
}
```

[From the docs on class properties:](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

> They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

In your first attempt, using `$this` outside an instance method would not have been supported even baring the compile-time limitation of property initialization, since `$this` is only meaningful inside instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

$this does not exist outside a non-static method of your class.  Also, at initialization time, there is no $this yet.  Initialize your array in the constuctor method.